# Error getting when run code in Python "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().."

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

When i run below code in `Python`

```
cols_with_missing = (col for col in new_data.columns if new_data[col].isnull().any())
for col in cols_with_missing:
    new_data[col + '_was_missing'] = new_data[col].isnull()
```

then getting below error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Here new_data is a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Series.any()` returns a new `Series`, as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html).

To obtain a single value (a scalar), you need to pass `None` as axis argument.

```py
cols_with_missing = (col for col in new_data.columns if new_data[col].isnull().any(None))
```

Comment: Thanks Crissal, I just missed `None` as axis argument. Now i got it

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```py
cols_with_missing = (col for col in new_data.columns if new_data[col].isnull().sum() > 0)
for col in cols_with_missing:
    new_data[col + '_was_missing'] = new_data[col].isnull()
```